# How to "left join" two elements in a function?

Tags: r

I want to make a function that creates frequency tables for an entire dataset and then adds columns for the frequencies for the same variables but from a subset of data. I am struggling as I would need to join by label which r is reading as a function, not a list.

Setting up df/labels for reproducibility

```
    sudf<-data.frame("tc_sa"=c(1,0,1,1), "tc_dt"=c(0,0,1,1), 
    "tc_hh"=c(0,0,0,1), "tc_sumh"=c(1,1,0,0), "fop_lccg"=c(1,1,1,1), 
    "fop_ddf"=c(0,1,1,1))


    tcsu = c("tc_sa", "tc_dt", "tc_hh", "tc_sumh")


    tcsu_label = c("Substance use treatment", "Detoxification", " 
    "Transitional housing, halfway house, or sober home", "Treatment for 
    co-occurring substance use plus either serious mental health illness 
    in adults/serious emotional disturbance in children") 


    tcsu_df = data.frame(service = tcsu, label = tcsu_label)

    fop = c("fop_lccg", "fop_ddf")

    fop_label = c("Local, county, or community government", "Department 
    of Defense")
    fop_df = data.frame(service = fop, label = fop_label)

    categories = list(tcsu = tcsu, fop= fop)
```

Creating function for tables with labels created above

````
   
    for (i in 1:length(categories)){ # Takes all the categories from above and tells to run code for each
    
    table = sudf %>% 
        mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% # creates a unique id (can update with the 
    org id or survey id)
        select(id, categories[[i]]) %>%  # selects the services for the 
    particular category
        gather("service", "num", -id) %>%  # restructures the data to 
    long format
        filter(num == 1) %>% # keeps entries with a 1
        left_join(get(paste(names(categories[i]), "_df", sep = "")), by = 
    "service") %>% # uses labels created above
        group_by(label) %>% # groups by services 
        summarise(Number = n(), Percent = round((Number/nrow(sudf))*100, 
    digits = 2)) # groups by services 
    
    table2 = sumhsu %>% 
        mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% # creates a unique id (can update with the 
    org id or survey id)
        select(id, categories[[i]]) %>%  # selects the services for the 
    particular category
        gather("service", "num", -id) %>%  # restructures the data to 
    long format
        filter(num == 1) %>% # keeps entries with a 1
        left_join(get(paste(names(categories[i]), "_df", sep = "")), by = 
    "service") %>% # uses labels created above
        group_by(label) %>% # groups by services 
        summarise(Number = n(), Percent = 
    round((Number/nrow(sumhsu))*100, digits = 2))
    
    table3<-table%>%left_join(table2, by = label)%>% 
        kable(caption =names(categories[i]), col.names = c(' ', 'Number', 
    'Percent', 'Number', 'Percent')) %>% # lists names of categories
        kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria") #formats 
    table
    
    print(table3) #prints table
    
    }
    
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Please give some sample data to run the code and/or put the question in reproducible form